# Responsive Design for Website

Tags: html, css, laravel-5, responsive-design

I am building my project. I just noticed that I made a big mistake with using just pixel values in tables, sidebars etc. So it makes a problem, like if other person has different resolution in computer my website looks shapeless and bad.

Which codes I should use to apply responsive design?

As I know to use width, height values with % is useful. Also I don't know exactly how to use % values. What else I should do?

Comment: You need to add <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: I should add this code to header part you mean yeah? Like it will apply a general changes according to devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use "rem" units to avoid problems (including the "media" max/min widths).

Consider 1rem = 16px for your desktop desing and 99.99% times everything goes well even in almost unknown devices.

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#font-relative-lengths

EDIT: (cause the comment)

There are different things.
1.- Use "rem" to size things (like font-size: 0.875rem in spite of font-size:14px) to keep thing with adecuate proportions to the size of the pixels, 2.- Use @media queries to change layout when the screen is to wide/to narrow, that sizing can be done in rems to, so min-width 20rem means (more or less) the width of 20 "M" letters (not really true, but close).

Let say you have a 24 inchs screen with 1480px, and your friend have also 1480px, but in just 6 inchs. If you make font size 12 px you will see pretty nice, but probably your friend will find it small. The device/browser developers can define a different rem size, acording to the physical size of the device (24px, for example) and your 0.875 rem will be 21 pixels in his screen (not so small, more comfortable to see)

The change in layout to adapt to a narrow screen can be done using those rems also, so for the same 1480px he can have a more comfortable layout. You have a screen 1480/16=92,5 rems width, but he have 1480/20=74 rems width.

Comment: like for example I have 1440x900 px, and my friend had a different resolution but he had a problem with visual of elements of my website. After I use rem, wont be the same problem? Because I mean pixel or rem will mean exact number, so if I say 10rem, It will move element 10rem, and It wont look in proper position If this person have a bigger resolution no?

Comment: ok I got it, feels like rem can be very useful for designing of small elements! Thank you miguel :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use percentage values just like you would use pixel values. If you want 1/4th of your website to be a sidebar, it can be as easy as:

```
.container { 
   width: 75% 
}
.sidebar { 
   width: 25% 
}
```

This wil make the container take up 75% of the browsers window. Since there is 25% space left, you could neatly fit a sidebar next to it by making that 25% width (you might need to add `float:left` to both elements).

However, I can image that on mobile view you would like your container and sidebar to be 100% width. You can do this by using [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp):

```
//medium phone size
@media screen (max-width: 425px) {
   .container {
      width: 100%
   }
   .sidebar {
      width: 100%
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you! I think I got my answer more less, just I need to investigate bit detailed about small elements maybe.

Comment: @Berke no problem! You can use percentage values on pretty much every HTML element, so I'm sure you will figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions:

- Use media queries to your pages.
- Use a [CSS grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp) (*and media queries*)
- Use [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) (*and media queries*)
- Use an other css framework including a grid system

Comment: ah yeah, actually my all tables are css grids. I actually need to ask about more small elements, like for example a button. Can i apply same col- values to buttons, or forms ?

Comment: yeah will do! Thank you guys, thanks to everyone. You are very kind to explain nice tips for people like me! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can start with [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com). That will not only make your site responsive but also there are many predefined designs for the HTML elements like buttons, fonts, tables etc. You will only have to use the classes.

If you are not well accustomed to Bootstrap the do as @Damian Makkink and @Marc_DNL have posted.

IMO a self-built CSS for a responsive site and design is better. Initially, in my hobby project, I started with Bootstrap but I have completely phased that out.